# how to create 2 columns based on dates in R?

Tags: r

I would like to determine classes based on the month and year of the column "dtcoleta", 1 column based on the month classified as 1 or 2 (November-March = 1) and (April-October = 2), and the other column based on year (2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, etc.)

I have collection dates in different years and months would like to sort by these conditions year 1 or 2 or year collection.

dtcoleta    est_col     year_col

03/02/13
03/02/13
04/13/14
01/29/13
03/09/14
02/22/15
03/02/13
01/29/16
03/02/13
09/14/13
08/03/15
07/12/16
01/29/14
08/03/13
03/02/13
07/12/13
01/29/13
06/12/14
04/13/13
03/02/16
07/12/13
10/19/15

---

========================================================================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lubridate library and the dplyr library will be helpful here. You can use lubridate to get the year of a date:

```
year(somedate)
```

And you can use a case_when() statement along with lubridate's month() function to get a column of ones and twos based on the month:

```
mutate(dtcoleta,
       newcolumn = case_when(month(est_col) >= 11 | month(est_col) <= 3 ~ 1,
                             month(est_col) >= 4 & month(est_col) <= 10 ~ 2)
```

This code says "when the result of month(est_col) is greater than or equal to 11 OR less than or equal to 3, set newcolumn to 1; when month(est_col) is between 4 and 10, set it equal to 2.